# How to make a singleton in Typescript work across multiple modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, singleton

I have a Database class in a typescript application I'm using that's set up as a singleton like so:

```
export default class Database {
    private static instance: Database;

    //Actual class logic removed

    public static getInstance(): Database {
        if (!Database.instance) {
            Database.instance = new Database();
            Database.instance.logger.debug("Creating new Database Instance");
        } else {
            Database.instance.logger.debug("Using existing Database Instance");
        }
        return Database.instance;
    }
}
```

When I import the module into another file using `import databaseService from "../services/database.service";` and get the instance using `private database = databaseService.getInstance();` it works as expected, and creates a new instance. Any further attempts to `getInstance()` in the **same file** then use that existing object.

However, if I then do the same in another file, it creates another new instance of the Database object. This is a no-no as eventually it'll mess up how the database logic works.

How can I get a single object set up to be shared across the entire application? Preferably without passing the object around everywhere, but if that's how it has to be then so be it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the eventual solution to this issue was, as mentioned in the comments of the answer given by Estus, double checking the cases of the imported modules.

`import databaseService from "../services/Database.service";` and 
`import databaseService from "../services/database.service";` both result in different instances of the singleton, but won't flag up as an issue on a case-insensitive OS.

Once all references were corrected to use the same case, the issue was solved and only once Database object was created.

Comment: I have the same problem here!!, I make sure to have the same import statement. but without success , it still give a different instance.

Answer (score 3):

Singleton classes are potential antipatterns in JavaScript because an instance of a class without inheritance could be expressed as plain object.

Explicit implementation of singleton pattern in class constructor is an antipattern in Node.js and other modular environments because modules already provide singletons.

It can be:

```
export class Database {}

export default new Database();
```

Where exported class may be useful for extensibility, in TypeScript it is  necessary for typing because it acts as an interface.

Comment: Potential bad / good practice aside (although yes, best practice would be better), relying on node.js's module implementation doesn't work any better than my current code - switching doesn't actually solve the issue I'm having. 

(With that in mind I've seen nothing to suggest that TS's singleton pattern is an antipattern before, but I'm not too precious about it)

Comment: *However, if I then do the same in another file, it creates another new instance of the Database object. This is a no-no as eventually it'll mess up how the database logic works.* - I don't see any explanation for this. The only possibility would be to evaluate this module multiple times, e.g. to import a module with different case in case-insensitive OS. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: Fair enough. Simplifying the code way down to bare-bones doesn't appear to cause the issue, so I'll do some poking around and see what the exact behaviour is and get back to you.